# Is there anything I can do with LUX weapon?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I am a returning player and have the blm lux weapon. Is there anything I can do with it? Such as exchange it to skip a step or two in the latest relic upgrade path (Eureka I think).

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, Lux weapons weren't given the same treatment that Zeta weapons were. All it's good for now is glamour.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing, considering all the work (time) that went into it. I was also far into two other weapon quests. I may as well abandon those then. Thank you for your answer.